# How to minimize $\Big( \frac{2}{a^2}+\frac{1}{b^2}\Big)(a^2+b^2)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

I've tried completing the square but I can't however i think there's something called a cauchy schwarz inequality that could help me solve this. Help?

But how $\frac2{a^2}$ is not a square number for the inequality $$(++)^2\le(^2+^2+^2)(^2+^2+^2)$$ do you split it into $\frac1{a^2}+\frac1{a^2}$?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: As you stated yourself, just apply the Cauchy Inequality.

Comment: But how 2/a^2 is not a square number for the inequality(++)2≤(^2+^2+^2)(^2+^2+^2) do you split it into 1/a^2+1/a^2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AM-GM

$3+2(b^2/a^2)+(a^2/b^2) \ge$

$3+2\sqrt{2(b^2/a^2)(a^2/b^2)}=$

$3+2\sqrt{2};$

Equality:

$2(b^2/a^2)=(a^2/b^2);$

$2b^4=a^4,$ or $a^2=\sqrt{2}b^2.$

Comment: Damn creative so many ways for one question

Comment: Tom Xia. The above is in  way straight forward. I consider the other answers more creative.

Comment: wow so humble but thank you very much. I'm in year 9 and trying to get ahead just learnt about the amgm property with the arithmetic and geometric mean. But anyway thank you again. Have a nice day.

Comment: Tom Xia. Hope you do well. Greetings, Peter

Answer (score 2):

As you stated

$$\left( \left( \frac{\sqrt2}a\right)^2 + \left(\frac1b\right)^2\right)\left( a^2+b^2\right) \ge \left(\sqrt2 + 1 \right)^2$$

Now, let's check if it can be attained.

If $b=1$ and $a=\sqrt[4]2$,

$$\left( \left( \frac{\sqrt2}{\sqrt[4]2}\right)^2 + \left(\frac11\right)^2\right)\left( \sqrt[4]2^2+1^2\right) = \left(\sqrt2 + 1 \right)^2$$

Comment: Thanks so much mate much appreciated. First time using stack and I see its a very good platform to use. Have a nice day.

Comment: Also just another question do you have to check the answer because sometimes the inequality doesn't work or what? Is it just a good habit?

Comment: Oh, I have proven a lower bound, but I want to check attainability. So yup, we know how to make it equal in this case by letting $\frac{\sqrt2}{a}=a$ and $\frac1b=b$.

Answer (score 2):

Just expand to find $$2+1+\dfrac{2b^2}{a^2}+\dfrac{a^2}{b^2}=3+\left(\dfrac{\sqrt2b}a-\dfrac ab\right)^2+2\sqrt2\ge3+2\sqrt2$$

the equality occurs if $\dfrac{\sqrt2b}a-\dfrac ab\iff\sqrt2b^2=a^2$ with $a,b$ non zero finite real

Comment: Just wondering why when completing the square with 2sqrt(2) why can't you have completed the square as (√2b/a+a/b)^2? and min as 3-2sqrt(2) does it even matter?

Comment: @TomXia, If $$\dfrac{\sqrt2b}a+\dfrac ab=0, \dfrac{b^2}{a^2}=?$$  Now we are dealing with real $a,b$ right?

Comment: ah yes I see now yep the answer supposed to be in domain R

Comment: @TomXia, The AM-GM inequality also needs each summand to be $\ge0$ right?

Comment: Oh yeah that was the condition

Answer (score 1):

Let $c=a/b.$ Then $$\left(\frac {2}{a^2}+\frac {1}{b^2}\right)(a^2+b^2)\,=\,3+\frac {2b^2}{a^2}+\frac {a^2}{b^2}=$$ $$=3+\frac {2}{c^2} +c^2=$$ $$=3+ \left(\frac {\sqrt 2}{c}-c\right)^2+2\sqrt 2\ge$$ $$\ge 3+2\sqrt 2$$ with equality iff $\frac {\sqrt 2}{c}-c=0,$ that is, iff $\frac {a^2}{b^2}=c^2=\sqrt 2.$